# Why can't i access the x variable of the bitmap? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, position, easeljs

I'm trying to loop through 3 images in my array and add it to the stage (using easelJS). I want to position it as well. When I try to access the images in the array i get an error saying that the I can't set x of undefined. Why can't the x variable of the easeljs Bitmap be accessed?

```
function displayPosters() {

    getPosters(); //get all images and assign it to designated array

            console.log(frontPosters);
            console.log(frontPosters.length);

    if(currentCat == Category.HOME) { //if current category is HOME

        for(var i = 0; i < frontPosters.length; i++) { //loop through posters

            frontPosters[i].x = 40; //set x position for testing, also where error occurs
            stage.addChild(frontPosters[i]); //add poster to stage

        }

    }

}
```

here is the code for loading and pushing those images into the frontPosters arrray.

```
var frontPosters = new Array(3);

function getPosters() {

    var games = new Image(); //create 3 images
    var apps = new Image();
    var aboutme = new Image();

    games.onload = function() { //add image to frontImages array on load

        var gamesPost = new createjs.Bitmap(games);
        frontPosters[0] = gamesPost;

    };

    apps.onload = function() {

        var appPost = new createjs.Bitmap(apps);
        frontPosters[1] = appPost;

    };

    aboutme.onload = function() {

        var amPost = new createjs.Bitmap(aboutme);
        frontPosters[2] = amPost;

    };

    games.src = "images/assets/posters/games_poster.jpg"; 
    apps.src = "images/assets/posters/apps_poster.jpg";
    aboutme.src = "images/assets/posters/aboutme_poster.jpg";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for(poster in frontPosters)` is bad practice, because you're actually iterating over the Array **Object** and not the values (a.k.a. the Array itself). Use `for(var i=0; i<frontPosters.length; i++)` instead. It's the easiest solution, IMO.

```
for(var i = 0; i < frontPosters.length; i++) { //loop through posters
    frontPosters[i].x = 40; //set x position for testing, also where error occurs
    stage.addChild(frontPosters[i]); //add poster to stage
}
```

**Edit**

I think you are dealing with a race-condition. You are going over your array **before** all images were loaded. By setting `var frontPosters = new Array(3);` you automatically set three values to `undefined` which are pushed into the new array.

You should check that all images were loaded before proceeding with the script.

Here's an idea for you. Set a callback that will run only after the third image was loaded.

```
var frontPosters = new Array(3);

function getPosters(callback) {

    var games   = new Image(),
        apps    = new Image(),
        aboutme = new Image(),
        loaded  = 0;

    games.onload = function() {
        frontPosters[0] = new createjs.Bitmap(this);
        if (++loaded === 3) callback();
    };

    apps.onload = function() {
        frontPosters[1] = new createjs.Bitmap(this);
        if (++loaded === 3) callback();
    };

    aboutme.onload = function() {
        frontPosters[2] = new createjs.Bitmap(this);
        if (++loaded === 3) callback();
    };

    games.src   = "images/assets/posters/games_poster.jpg"; 
    apps.src    = "images/assets/posters/apps_poster.jpg";
    aboutme.src = "images/assets/posters/aboutme_poster.jpg";

}

function displayPosters() {

    getPosters(function() {
        if(currentCat == Category.HOME) { //if current category is HOME
            for(var i = 0; i < frontPosters.length; i++) { //loop through posters
                frontPosters[i].x = 40; //set x position for testing, also where error occurs
                stage.addChild(frontPosters[i]); //add poster to stage
            }
        }
    }); //get all images and assign it to designated array, only after all images were loaded

}
```

Comment: the problem is that when i do "frontPosters[0].x = 40;" or something like that, the error still occurs.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's impossible to help you as long as we have no idea what `frontPosters` contains. You could try adding `console.log(frontPosters);` before the `for` loop, then open your dev-tools (or firebug) console and see what the array contains. If it doesn't clarify things add it to your original post, at least we'll know what we're dealing with.

Comment: i said it contained 3 images. but if it helps I'll post the code that handles those images.

Comment: If you get `can't set x of undefined` then it's either not contains what you think it contains or this is not the origin of the error. This is my analysis :)

Comment: You're right their isn't anything in them when I use console.log, but for some reason it says that it contains 3 objects when I do console.log(frontPosters.length);

Comment: Because you've set it to three values when initiating the array :) I've edited my answer, btw.

Comment: Yeah 3 Bitmap objects, or so I thought.

Comment: Hope my example helps. Let me know if you have any questions